# How to request Web API OAuth token using HttpClient in a C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, httpclient, access-token

I'm new in WPF and want to call oauth token api to get authenticated token through HttpClient. I have tried many solutions but still getting response Bad request(400).
I have checked with postman as well, api works fine.
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUvmN.png)

**Tried Solutions:**
**(1)**

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.apiClient.SendAsync(request))
{
    Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> StatusCode -> " + response.StatusCode);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //ComicModel comic = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ComicModel>();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> exception -> " + response);
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

**(2)**

```
using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(param))
{
    content.Headers.Clear();
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.apiClient.PostAsync(url, content))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> StatusCode -> " + response.StatusCode);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //ComicModel comic = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ComicModel>();
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> exception -> " + response);
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

**(3)**

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.apiClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(param)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> StatusCode -> " + response.StatusCode);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //ComicModel comic = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ComicModel>();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("postRequest -> exception -> " + response);
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

All solutions respond me 400 bad request.
My params are:

```
var params= new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            params.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
            params.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myUsername")));
            params.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myPass")));
```

How can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check with postman, and check the datastrings you're sending

Comment: @BugFinder yes I have checked with postman. everything is fine in my api.

Comment: @BugFinder checkout my postman response I've  added postman screenshot

Comment: In your postman, you have 9 headers you're sending on top of the 3 keys, whats in there?

Comment: @BugFinder only one header which is Content-Type and value is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, rest are temporary

Comment: but it maybe those temporary things are making the difference, eg a cookie, or a reference to help prevent bots?

Comment: @BugFinder no I don't thing so. These are added by postman. I have attached these headers but nothing work

Comment: Oops! my base url starts with http. I forgot to replace it with https. Everything is fine with https. Thanks @BugFinder for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you authenticate with Postman ?
I do not see it in your code. It depends on how the api is configured.
Be sure to use the appropriate auth method in your client call, for example Bearer token. Api should return 400 instead of 401.

```
httpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
```

Comment: please look at my problem Dmo. I need this access token from api. This request is calling token api to access this token.

Comment: [Are you using this flow ?](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/src/ConsoleResourceOwnerFlowUserInfo/Program.cs) It might help you (using IdentityServer4)

Answer (score 0):

Oops! my base url starts with http. I forgot to replace it with https. Everything is fine with https. :)
Thanks